# SQL Server stored procedure + set error message from the records of a table

Tags: sql-server

My question is I have a table with the set of records. I am calling a stored procedure for some other purpose. But when ever it finds some duplicate records. It need to return as error message back to php.

```
    C1             C2               c3
   abc             32              21.03.2010          
   def             35              04.04.2010          
   pqr             45              30.03.2010            
   abc             12              04.05.2010         
   xyz             56              01.03.2010         
   ghi             21              06.05.2010   
   def             47              17.02.2010    
   klm             93              04.03.2010 
   xyz             11              01.03.2010
```

For the above set it need to check for the records that has the same c1. 
The stored procedure should return as abc,def,xyz are duplicate.

I tried something like this. This will not work it has more than 1 set of duplicate records. Please help me to enhance this to solve the purpose.

```
SET @duplicate = (SELECT c1 FROM temp GROUP BY c1 HAVING count(c1) > 1)
--Check for duplicate concession Nr.
IF(len(@duplicate) > '1') 
BEGIN
SET @error = @error + ' Duplicate C1 Number:- ' + @duplicate
SET @errorcount = @errorcount + 1
END
```

As this one type error I am checking for errorcount.

```
IF @errorcount <> '0'
BEGIN
GOTO E_General_Error
END

 -- If an error occurs, rollback and exit
 E_General_Error:
    PRINT 'Error'
SET @error =  @error
IF @@error <> 0 SET @error = 'Database update failed'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION update_database
    RETURN 
END
```

Now it is able to return Duplicate c1 number abc. If there are more than 1 problem comes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a cursor to concatenate them all into one report string. You can do

```
DECLARE @duplicate VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @duplicate = ''

SELECT @duplicate = @duplicate + '
Duplicate C1 Number:- ' + CONVERT(varchar(100),c1) 
FROM temp 
GROUP BY c1 
HAVING count(c1) > 1
```

If you need the Count appended you can probably do something with `@@rowcount` after the above has run.

Comment: It, worked like a charm. Thanku for ur quick response. I some how tried this way without set @duplicate = ''. It did not worked for me. It would be great if you can explain me why we need to initialise it.

Comment: @Lucky. The only reason you need to initialise it is because if you concatenate NULL with a string you end up with NULL. It is possible to avoid the initialisation with COALESCE which is useful when you don't want the additional delimiter added as here http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/cat.txt

Answer (score 1):

By setting the results of your query to that variable, you're only returning the first row. In this case, I think you'd need to use a CURSOR to get it done, since you're looking to process each row. Is this along the lines of what you're looking to do?

```
DECLARE @Duplicate VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @Results VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR
FOR SELECT c1 FROM temp GROUP BY c1 HAVING count(c1) > 1

OPEN cursor_name
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name into @Duplicate

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
BEGIN

   SET @Results = Results & @Duplicate & ', '

   OPEN cursor_name
   FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name into @Duplicate

END

CLOSE cursor_name
DEALLOCATE cursor_name

IF LEN(@Results) > 2
BEGIN
   SET @Results = LEFT(@Results, LEN(@Results)-2)
   SET @error = @error + ' Duplicate C1 Number:- ' + @duplicate
   SET @errorcount = @errorcount + 1
END
```

Comment: Thanku for ur quick response:-)